# bootstrap alert method with no parameter

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, alert

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/

I'm new on bootstrap 4.0 and I was reading the documentation and i found this method:

```
$('.alert').alert()
```

> Makes an alert listen for click events on descendant elements which
>   have the data-dismiss="alert" attribute. (Not necessary when using the
>   data-api’s auto-initialization.)

So to test this method i tried the following code:

```
$(document).off('.alert.data-api'); // worked
$('.alert').alert(); // do nothing!

<div id='mydiv' class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
text
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
```

The alert() method is doing nothing! The button still does not work! So my question is, why is it not working?

Comment: Does the element's descendant has a `dismiss="alert"`attribute, as stated in the doc? It does not seem to be.

Comment: yes it has! i added the html. you can test it by yourself

Comment: "$(...).alert('close');"  is working but "$(...).alert();" is NOT!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may misunderstand the usage of `$(selector).alert()`. Calling the alert function without any parameters simply tells bootstrap to listen for clicks on **children** elements containing `data-dismiss="alert"` - see the example below.

In your example you don't close 'myDiv' which is why your code isn't functioning as the close button isn't within the alert div.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#alertDiv').alert()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='alertDiv' class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  Alert Message!
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: i closed the "myDiv" on my test but forgot to paste it on stackoverflow! About your example, the button would work even without your javascript code "$('#alertDiv').alert()". so this is not testing the method at all!